# Select statement fails to populate textbox

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've currently got these two select statements however the first statement works perfect and populates the fields below however the second one doesn't populate the desired field.

```
<php?
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
      {
       $articleID = $_GET['id'];
       $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM article WHERE articleID = "' .    $articleID . '"');
       $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       $stmt2 = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE artID = "' . $articleID . '"');
       $result2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      }
    ?>


                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label class="labels">Article Category:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="articlecate" value="<?php echo $result['articlecate'] ?>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

This one works fine and the article category is populated.

```
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label class="labels">Article Name:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="articlename" value="<?php echo $result2['name'] ?>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

This don't throw any error just simply don't show anything in the field.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: $result2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); you have to use  <input type="text" name="articlename" value="<?php echo $result2['name'] ?>" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this,

```
$stmt2 = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE artID = "' . $articleID . '"');
   $result2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to this,

```
$stmt2 = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE artID = "' . $articleID . '"');
   $result2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

you are doing wrong **$stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)** here.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '**' (T_POW) in /srv/http/readmore.php on line 14

Comment: That works thank you! Would there be a way to implement  a if $comment = 'approved' ?

Comment: Only display the comment if its approved

Comment: like this?? `<input type="text" name="articlename" value="<?php if($result2['comment']=='approved') echo $result2['name'] ?>" />`

Comment: if  my answer helped you please accept it and vote up

Comment: Thats right, i've just realized i've got to display multiple comments on the same article so i'm not sure this is the best method

Answer (score 0):

`$stmt2 = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE artID = "' . $articleID . '"');
$result2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Replace with this line

`$stmt2 = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE artID = '$articleID'");
$result2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`